# Programmatically change the tile on WP7 device

Tags: windows-phone-7, icons, push-notification, tile

I'm making an app where I would like to generate a new tile from inside the app, and then change it - no web service involved, and no need to change it when the app is not running.

Anyone know how to do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

as @Derek said, you can update the tile using the tile schedule, but will take an hour minimum before the phone updates the tile.

i have written a tutorial on how to update the tile instantly here:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/04/03/windows-phone-7-live-tile-schedules-ndash-executing-instant-live-tile-updates

basically it involves opening a push/toast update channel and then getting the phone to send "itself" a live tile update request. this will trigger the phone to go and get the tile "right now"

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can update the background image for a Live tile by using the `ShellTileSchedule` as documented in [How to: Update Your Tile Without Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769548%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). However, the image that is used for that background **must** come from a remote location, it cannot be provided directly by your application (unless you generate the image and send it to your own web service).

If you do go down the Microsoft Push Notification Services route, you may want to take a look at the [Windows Push Notification Server Side Helper Library](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/01/14/windows-push-notification-server-side-helper-library.aspx) provided by the Windows Phone team.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate and send a tile push notification message from the applicaiton itself. Not sure if it will work with an image in the app though. - Let us know if you try.

Comment: It doesn't work with an image from the app - relative URLs are not accepted by the scheduler and in order to change the tile you would need access to native methods (unfortunately marked as SecuritySafeCritical).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info!

It won't be an image from the app, as the xml files I'm downloading are pointing to the correct image. Not sure about the format, but I guess setting up my own server to proxy the request and resize the icon as needed wouldn't be too hard.

But it's really sad we cannot manipulate the tile image for 'this' from within our own app...